I hate it when my jello starts to congeal and gets that funky skin on the top!

I hate it when my jello starts to congeal and gets that funky skin on the top!

What's the meaning of 'funky' here?

having the style or feeling of funk music

stylish or appealing in an unusual way

having a strange or unpleasant odor



American English mainly. It's very slang and casual and means something like 'unpleasant, repulsive, nasty, repellent, unappetising, etc. FUNKY | English meaning - Cambridge Dictionary (BAD). US informal. having a bad smell or appearance: "The sour cream smells kind of funky."

You need to explain why this is a problem for you.  Do you know what "Jello" is?  If you do you should be able to remove two of your suggestions because the make absolutely no sense, in context.

so many meanings are there. confusing.

Not 'confusing'. The meaning is obvious. A skin on top is something you can see. 'I hate it' (so it's bad.) So, clearly, having a bad appearance. We can tell you about language, but you have to do some thinking yourself.

@gomadeng  No, there are three meanings there.  One is obviously irrelevant, another is obviously contradictory.  That leave one left,   There is only one meaning.  I hope you can see what it is.  I suggest you write a self answer.

In my three examples of meaning, 'bad' one is no. 3. In other words, 'in an unusual way+stylish or appealing' does not contain 'bad'.

Exactly.  If the speaker 'hates' it, they obviously don't mean definition 2.

@KateBunting Definition 3 mentioned only 'odor'. That's why it was confusing.

Dictionaries are letting me down today. I was highly inclined to close this question as perversely obtuse, because obviously the skin on jello is not musical or fashionable. But it's also not usually stinky.
What I was looking for in dictionaries, and haven't really found much of, is a usage in which "funky" simply means weird, as in "I'm feeling funky," to mean "a little unsettled, but not sure exactly how." It's a bit of a colloquial use, but then so are pretty much all usages of "funky."
Merriam Webster comes close with "odd or quaint in appearance or feeling," though adding "or quaint," and giving the example "a funky little restaurant" suggests a positive connotation. But the synonym section below lists bizarre, odd, queer, strange, screwy, and weird. And several of their examples auto-collected from the web show this sense. There's mention of "Mars' funky moon Phobos"; Phobos is perhaps "quaint" but not musical or stylish, and I think astronomers would get very excited if it had a strong odor. And one example is taken from an article about the Ig Nobel prizes, describing the winning entries as "funky findings." Some, like a study of the hydrodynamics of dead fish, might well be stinky, but overall an earlier sentence summarized these studies as "bizarre science."
So, although I'm unable to find a dictionary entry that comes any closer than the M-W one above, I'm inclined to read the comment about the Jello skin as simply "unusual or odd."

jello with funky skin on top means:
icky, grotty or gross or sticky. Not something pleasing.
The dictionary meaning weird, goes with icky.
